# Is there any way to perform click event on device if we get screen co-ordinates from server?

Tags: android, remote-desktop

I'm getting x-y coordinates from the server I want to perform the click on the device according to the given coordinate. How can it be possible? A reference like a team viewer (RDC).

Comment: your logic might fail while testing on different screen sizes of devices where the coordinates will vary according to the screen size. you should find another solution for the problem.

Comment: You need to create your own RDP protocol to manage info like screen size, screen coordinates, events, etc. on the target device. There is an open source RDP http://www.freerdp.com/

Comment: instead of coordinate i think using element id will be better choice, as for diiferent sizes and resolution your logic may fail

Comment: @AnkitMehta I am getting the coordinates according to the screen size. I already Developed that mechanism. Problem is M unable to perform action on Non Knox non Rooted device

Answer (score 1):

You can't simulate clicks/touches on non-Rooted devices due to Security reasons, especially if you would like to send them OUTSIDE your Activities.

On Rooted phones there are few methods: (1) directly write access to "/dev/input/..." touchscreen device or (2) use a shell command (but it could be slow if you need to send many X,Y coords in short time)

Comment: Thanks for the answer actually I need it mainly for the non-rooted device.